# Automate pairwise comparisons between subsets in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, plyr

I have a data.frame with several variables X1,X2... and a grouping variable "site" I want to find the proportion of X1 with site==1 greater than X1 with site==2, I can do that with a fixed number of site levels and each variable at a time, but I would like to generalize for any number of levels and several variables, following is an example:

```
# Generate data
set.seed(20130226)

n <- 100
x1 <- matrix(c(rnorm(n, mean = 2),rnorm(n, mean = 5)),ncol=2)
x2 <- matrix(c(rnorm(n, mean = 1), rnorm(n, mean = 4)),ncol=2)
x3 <- matrix(c(rnorm(n, mean = 3), rnorm(n, mean = 3)),ncol=2)
xx <- data.frame(x1,site=1)
xx <- rbind(xx, data.frame(x2,site=2))
xx <- rbind(xx, data.frame(x3,site=3))

# comparisons

s <- unique(xx$site)
me1 <- with(xx,xx[site==s[1],])
me2<- with(xx,xx[site==s[2],])
me3<- with(xx,xx[site==s[3],])

Pg1.gt.g2 <- sum(me1[,c("X1")]>me2[,c("X1")])/nrow(me1)
Pg1.gt.g3 <- sum(me1[,c("X1")]>me3[,c("X1")])/nrow(me1)
Pg2.gt.g3 <- sum(me2[,c("X1")]>me3[,c("X1")])/nrow(me1)

# build table
comp1 <- data.frame(Group=c(paste(s[1],">",s[2]),paste(s[1],">",s[3]),paste(s[2],">",s[3])),  P=c(Pg1.gt.g2, Pg1.gt.g3,Pg2.gt.g3))

print(comp1)
```

I don't figure out how to do this for a different numbers of groups and several variables, maybe using plyr

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reshape the data into a matrix where each column represents a group:

```
# Unique sites
s <- unique(xx$site)

# Columns are each group, data are X1 values
mat <- do.call(cbind, lapply(split(xx, xx$site), function(x) x$X1))

# Compare all pairs of sites
do.call(rbind, apply(combn(seq_along(s), 2), 2,
                     function(x) data.frame(g1=s[x[1]], g2=s[x[2]],
                                            prop=sum(mat[,x[1]] > mat[,x[2]])/nrow(mat))))

#   g1 g2 prop
# 1  1  2 0.83
# 2  1  3 0.20
# 3  2  3 0.09
```

Comment: Clever,  can't understand very well the last do.call. Anyway this is for X1, but if you have an undefined number of variables?

Comment: If you wanted to do it for a different variable, you would need to change how you created `mat` -- everything else would be the same. If you wanted to compute the table for many different variables, you could make this code a function and pass the variable name (here it would have been "X1").